# Replace multiple value by using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot

I'm working with MongoDB and Spring Boot. When I execute a query, I can get the query log in the terminal like following.

```
[{ "$match" : { "$and" : [{ "type" : "VIDEO"}, { "excludeUserIds" : { "$not" : { "$elemMatch" : { "$and" : [{ "_id" : 23}, { "groupIds" : { "$in" : [{ "$oid" : "5f434c9b51a7ff3214158a42"}, { "$oid" : "5f113ed4fd775a238ee5ce59"}.......
```

To check whether its working fine or not, I need to copy the query and paste the above query in Mongo compass which is a tool that helps to execute queries in multiple stages.

But the problem is, `[{ "$oid" : "5f434c9b51a7ff3214158a42"}, { "$oid" : "5f113ed4fd775a238ee5ce59"}]` this format cannot be used in the Mongo compass. Instead of that, we have to use `ObjectId` as a wrapper like following. (Kind of replacing on `{ "$oid" :` )

```
[ObjectId("5f434c9b51a7ff3214158a42"), ObjectId("5f113ed4fd775a238ee5ce59")]
```

I'm getting more than 50 ObjectId at a time in multiple places. My plan is to find each and every objects (`{ "$oid" : "the_value"}`) using regex and replace by `ObjectId("the_value")`.

The regex `\{\s\"([a-zA-Z\\d$]+)\"\s:\s\"([^\"]*)\"}` is finding all the objects. But I'm struggling at replacing the same value on the place.

So I wrote a program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/input.txt"));
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/output.txt");
        String str = "";

        try {
            while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\\s\\\"([a-zA-Z\\\\d$]+)\\\"\\s:\\s\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"}");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

                if (m.find()) {
                    str = m.replaceAll("ObjectId('" + m.group(2) + "')");
                }
                writer.write(str);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        }
        writer.close();
        reader.close();
    }
```

### Update 1

Now I'm getting `........{ "$in" : [ObjectId('VIDEO'), ObjectId('VIDEO')`. That doesn't get the exact value (`5f434c9b51a7ff3214158a42`, `5f113ed4fd775a238ee5ce59`) I want.

Comment: You need to explain what problem you're having. "Bug I'm struggling at replacing the same value on the place." doesn't explain what is happening.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience in explaining. I have updated my question

Comment: Strictly speaking you can't do it by regular expression because JSON is not regular language. JSON is at least context independent language. So, if you use java, do it by using the json parser and process it in a language specific maner. Ok, you can use regex, but is not a correct and reliable way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Replace All with Regex - substitute with Variable and multiple value**

**Alternative Regex:**

```
"\\{\\s\"\\$oid\"\\s:\\s\"(\\w+)\"\\}"
```

**Regex in context:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String file = System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Desktop/input.txt";
    String input = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file)));
    System.out.println(input);

    // { "$oid" : "the_value"} replaced by ObjectId("the_value")
    String regex = "\\{\\s\"\\$oid\"\\s:\\s\"(\\w+)\"\\}";
    String output = input.replaceAll(regex, "ObjectId(\"$1\")");
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

**Input:**

```
[{ "$match" : { "$and" : [{ "type" : "VIDEO"}, { "excludeUserIds" : { "$not" : { "$elemMatch" : { "$and" : [{ "_id" : 23}, { "groupIds" : { "$in" : [{ "$oid" : "5f434c9b51a7ff3214158a42"}, { "$oid" : "5f113ed4fd775a238ee5ce59"}]
```

**Output:**

```
[{ "$match" : { "$and" : [{ "type" : "VIDEO"}, { "excludeUserIds" : { "$not" : { "$elemMatch" : { "$and" : [{ "_id" : 23}, { "groupIds" : { "$in" : [ObjectId("5f434c9b51a7ff3214158a42"), ObjectId("5f113ed4fd775a238ee5ce59")]
```

**Summary Result:**

```
[{ "$oid" : "5f434c9b51a7ff3214158a42"}, { "$oid" : "5f113ed4fd775a238ee5ce59"}]
```

Was changed to:

```
[ObjectId("5f434c9b51a7ff3214158a42"), ObjectId("5f113ed4fd775a238ee5ce59")]
```

Comment: Wow, perfect. This is what I need. Thank you for the answer

Comment: You are welcome and no problem :) Here is a link that I use a lot when writting regex, maybe it can help you too: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using libraries, gson seems like the perfect match for your situation. Using gson, data would be parsed into a map.
You can use the map and construct outbound data in your custom format.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should Help. Feel Free to edit my answer it may help someone else.

```
 sed -E 's/\{\s\"([a-zA-Z\\d$]+)\"\s:\s\"([^\"]*)\"}/ObjectId(\2)/g' myFile.txt
```

[image]

This is grouping and replacing (tag based). Here \1 will represt the first group i.e. ($oid) and \2 represent the second group (objectId)

However if you would like to use the java program itself.
The Problem I see in your java program is that `m.group(2)`
is used with `m.replaceAll()`. As you said there are going to be more than 50 matches so `m.find()` will be true for 50 times but you are only replacing the matched text with `m.group(2)` once, so all those 50 occurrences should be replaced by the first matched value. ( In your case it is VIDEO I don't know how that is have to see your file for that)

I have made a simple program it should help as well.
Again feel free to edit or comment.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str = "[{ \"$oid\" : \"5f434c9b51a7ff3214158a42\"}, { \"$oid\" : \"5f113ed4fd775a238ee5ce59\"}]";
    final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{\\s\\\"([a-zA-Z\\\\d$]+)\\\"\\s:\\s\\\"([^\\\"]*)\\\"}");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

    String finalString = "[";
    while (m.find()) {
        finalString += "ObjectId('" + m.group(2) + "') ";
    }
    finalString += "]";
    System.out.println(finalString);
}
```